# connect to cassandra from java

Tags: java, hadoop, cassandra, nosql

My system has hadoop 2.8.0 and cassandra 3.11.0  and java installed on my   virtualbox . I want to connect to cassandra from java API directly ..my cassandra server is up  CQLSH> is working..i have written this program to connect to cassandra to build keyspace in vim editor in my centos.

```
 import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
 import com.datastax.driver.core.Host;  
 import com.datastax.driver.core.Metadata;
 import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
 public class Cas
 {
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  String query = "CREATE KEYSPACE tp WITH replication "
          + "= {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1};";

  Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").build();
    Session session = cluster.connect();
     session.execute(query);
     session.execute("USE tp");
     System.out.println("Keyspace created");
  }
```

}

I am new to cassandra and hadoop so please guide me some steps to run the code..any help would be appreciated..

Comment: I would recommend to use some IDE with Maven support - it will make life much easier!

Comment: But i want to  run the  code by passing cassandra jar through classpath..

Comment: that's was just advice for future, when you have more dependencies :-)

Comment: @Alex ..okayy..thanks :))